# Can Angular add a css class to a parent/sibling element when input is invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My form elements look like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="message.emailAddress" id="email" />
</div>
```

Angular automatically adds the class "ng-invalid" to the input when the email address is invalid - but I would also like it to add a class the label or the control-group.

**Is that possible? or is there an easy workaround?**

Comment: Adding this functionality yourself would require the use of a directive. You could maybe put an attribute directive on the control-group that detects if the input elemnt has the ng-invalid class and apply it to the label element as well if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are added to the parent `form` element labeled as `ng-invalid-inputName`. You could style off of this.

Answer (score 5):

If your form's name is *myForm*, you could add

```
ng-class="{'some-class-name': !myForm.email.$valid}"
```

to the label and/or control group element.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use angularjs [ng-style](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
ng-class="mode.input.$valid ? 'someclas': 'otherclass'";
```

or nested for multiple class or checks: 
as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970785/4812515[stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970785/4812515)

```
ng-class="model.input.$valid ? 'someclas': (model.input.$valid ? 'class':'class')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an error class to `.control-group` you can style the parent of the input, but also the label and input.

Just check the boolean `yourForm.email.$invalid` with `ng-class`. 
`yourForm` is the name attribute value of the form element and `email` the name attribute vale of the input element.

```
<form name="yourForm">
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{'control-group-error': yourForm.email.$invalid}">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="message.emailAddress" />
    </div>    
</form>
```