# AngularJS - Applying ng-class based on numbers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-class

I understand how to use ng-class for boolean values, e.g:

```
<div ng-class="{true: 'success', false: 'error'}[IsPositive]">
```

However, how do i perform based on a numeric value?

For example, if i have a $scope.myNumber, which can be any positive or negative value e.g.

-212

or

-31

or

0

or

31

or

123

How can i use an ng-class to apply 3 types of classes, that is, when:

```
$scope.myNumber > 0
$scope.myNumber < 0
$scope.myNumber == 0
```

Comment: Have a look at this question for some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172573/angular-ng-class-if-else-expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div ng-class="{'zero' : myNumber == 0, 
'negative' : myNumber < 0, 
'positive' : myNumber > 0}">
```

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
 <div ng-class="{'one': myNumber > 5 && myNumber < 10, 'two' : myNumber > 10, 'three' : myNumber < 5, 'equal' : myNumber === 0}"></div>
```

And you can see live:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zdaN53?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
<div ng-class="{'green':myNumber>0,'red':myNumber<0,'orange':myNumber==0}"> </div>
```