# Angular ng-class if else

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-class

I'd like to know how to do to make the False ng-class.

page.isSelected(1) is TRUE if the page if the page is selected, else FALSE

```
<div id="homePage" ng-class="{ center: page.isSelected(1) }">
```

I therefore want you if:

isSelected is TRUE: center

isSelected is FALSE: left

I tried:

```
<div id="homePage" ng-class="{ page.isSelected(1) 'center : 'left' }">
```

but it doesnt work.

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular ng-class if-else expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172573/angular-ng-class-if-else-expression)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Just make a rule for each case:

```
<div id="homePage" ng-class="{ 'center': page.isSelected(1) , 'left': !page.isSelected(1)  }">
```

Or use the ternary operator:

```
<div id="homePage" ng-class="page.isSelected(1) ? 'center' : 'left'">
```

Comment: [This is good sample for using ng-class without associating the value to model](https://codepen.io/DevelopIntelligenceBoulder/pen/rewObY/)

Answer (score 27):

You can use the ternary operator notation:

```
<div id="homePage" ng-class="page.isSelected(1)? 'center' : 'left'">
```

Comment: This is a better answer since it respect the DRY principle

Comment: This is much more elegant.

Answer (score 9):

Both [John Conde's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369250/angular-ng-class-if-else#answer-25369287) and [ryeballar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369250/angular-ng-class-if-else#answer-25369317) answers are correct and will work.

If you want to get too geeky:

- John's has the downside that it has to make two decisions per $digest loop (it has to decide whether to add/remove `center` and it has to decide whether to add/remove `left`), when clearly only one is needed.
- Ryeballar's relies on the ternary operator which is probably going to be removed at some point (because the view should not contain any logic). (We can't be sure it will indeed be removed and it probably won't be any time soon, but if there is a more "safe" solution, why not ?)

---

So, you can do the following as an alternative:

```
ng-class="{true:'center',false:'left'}[page.isSelected(1)]"
```

Comment: In light of your 2nd statement, is it possible that the `ng-class="[]"` notation can be removed as well? if not, then it is still possible to do it like this: `ng-class="[page.isSelected(1)? 'center : 'left']"`

Comment: The ternay operator will be removed from the "abilities" of the $parser (at least that's what Igor Minar is hoping for :)). This means that no expression containing the trnary operator will be parsable as an Angular Expression.