# Angular: How to mark needed row in table

Tags: angularjs

Is there any possibility to add CSS class "marked-row" to the TR-element in case if candidate.bl = TRUE ?

```
     <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="candidate in candidates | orderBy : orderByField : reverseSort">
            <td>{{candidate.fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{candidate.birthdate}}</td>
            <td><span ng-show="candidate.bl" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<tr data-ng-class="{'marked-row': candidate.bl}">
```

[angular ng-class if-else expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172573/angular-ng-class-if-else-expression)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <tr ng-class="{'marked-row':candidate.marked}" data-ng-repeat="candidate in candidates | orderBy : orderByField : reverseSort">
        <td>{{candidate.fullname}}</td>
        <td>{{candidate.birthdate}}</td>
        <td><span ng-show="candidate.bl" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
    </tr>
```