# How to give a specific class when title has certain length in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I can't get this to work.

```
<div ng-repeat="title in titles">
   <h1>{{title.name}}}</h1>
</div>
```

What I want to do, is to get the length of the title. So let's say if the title has 10 letters, I want to give it a specific class.

I tried this:

```
<h1 ng-class="title.name.length >= 10 ? 'specific-class'">{{title.name}}}</h1>
```

(found it here, by the way: [angular ng-class if-else expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172573/angular-ng-class-if-else-expression)).

But it didn't work, so clearly I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't need ternary operator. It could be the following:

```
<h1 ng-class="{'specific-class': title.name.length >= 10}">{{title.name}}</h1>
```

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rar92qd6/)

Comment: Thanks man. The thing is... it doesn't add the class to my classname. What am I doing wrong? No it just has class="ng-binding", but the new class isn't being added...

Comment: @Siyah I don't understand what your issue is. Could you provide your real code by forking my Fiddle?

Comment: @Siyah Glad I helped! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `terniary-operator` which best suits for these kind of situations.

You can add class based on both the `true` or `false` result of the condition.

Try this,

```
<h1 ng-class="((title.name.length) >= 10) ? 'specific-class' : 'other-class'">{{title.name}}}</h1>
```

**This once adds `specific-class` if condition satisfies and `other-class` if it fails**

Here is an example,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>

.specific-class {
    background-color:coral;
    padding:40px;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
</style>
<body ng-app="">

<div ng-class="(15 >= 10) ? 'specific-class' : ''">
  <h1>Welcome Home!</h1>
  <p>I like it!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

Comment: Same problem as above. It isn't being added to my class... It seems like it's not working, but probably something is wrong in my code in that case. Grr

Comment: add my code and check if the `other-class` is getting added on failed condition.

Comment: The code above worked. Thanks mate. I upvoted your answer!

Comment: @Siyah, glad to help you.