# How to apply the style within angular expressions

Tags: angularjs

I am having the below line of code which is having two values Absent and Present.If the value is Absent i want make it red colour and bold.I tried 
by applying style but it is not working.please suggest me how to do it .

code:

```
<div class="flex-2 bold1">{{attendance.status == 'Absent' ? "style='color:red;font-weight:bold'" :" "}}</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried ? Check `ng-class` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172573/angular-ng-class-if-else-expression

Comment: First off, what version of angular are you using here?

Comment: try to use `ng-class` instead.

Comment: @ Tom Makin i am using angular 1.5.7

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do that:

```
<div class="flex-2 bold1" ng-style="attendance.status == 'Absent' && {'color':'red','font-weight':'bold'}"></div>
```

Other is by using class (Recommended)

```
.highlighted {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold
}


ng-class="{'highlighted': attendance.status == 'Absent'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

using class (Recommended):
Create the style in class and mention it in ng-class with conditional operator

ng-class="{attendance.status == 'Absent'?'test': 'test1'}"